# Remote debugging not loading correct Symbols

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I have been running into a few issues with remote debugging in Visual Studio 2012u4. I followed [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534760/e-cCannotplusevaluateplusexpressionplusbecaus) set of instructions to ensure I am in debugging mode without optimizations.

I still get the same error: "Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized."

When I start up the project and attach to w3wp, I notice the symbols are not initially loaded (user code =no), I have to go into the Modules window and load them manually (right click -> load symbols). From here, I see it loads the Symbols from the obj\Release folder which seems odd.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just realized that I published the site with the Release profile, not debug. Problem solved.